# Playing and Controlling MP3 and FLV audio/videos (live strteam)with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, streaming-flv-video

Using JavaScript how can i control external FLV live audio/video (radio) stream.

I have URL say BBC Radio, which when entered in address bar of browser display its own FLV player.

I need to control this live stream to be play,pause,increase/decrease volume using JavaScript.

The JavaScript should be universal in the sense that, for any FLV player above functions are applicable.

Is it possible to do so using JS?

Please guide me.

FYI: I am using PHP,MYSQL and APACHE

Answer (score 0):

Much like an class exposes public methods to other parts of an application, a flash element must explicitly expose methods to JavaScript via the ExternalInterface API.  See [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/external_interface.html), [here](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/638/1/Basics-of-using-the-ExternalInterface/Page1.html) and [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

Comment: Hi Justin,
Thanks for prompt reply. As I am newbie to ExternalInterface API. Below is the URL which gives me their own FLV player. Now how can i determine the FLV player exposes any JS? Please guide me. 
http://player.streamtheworld.com/_players/entercom/player/?id=WJMH

Comment: Is this a proprietary solution?  I don't see any documentation.  Find it and you should have your answer.